# Incoming emails from SES all went into the Spams folder

Tags: amazon-ses

I am using SES to send out notification emails for my online website portal. However, I noticed that every email sent out from SES; all emails are going into the Spams folder.
Any ideas?

```
Please key in 982005 as your Access Account registration Verification Code.
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the raw message of the email sent from SES?

Comment: @jellycsc - Here you are the email content.

Comment: Could you also include the raw headers, not just the body?

Comment: @jellycsc - I have attached the screenshot here in the description.

Comment: @jellycsc- I noticed the issue is due to the DMARC setting in the Workmail and the Route53 domain settings. Any experience?